# Pygame window won't stay open

Tags: python, pygame

I decided to try and make the snake-eating dot game on my own. I can't make my pygame window stay open when I try and run what I have. How can I make it stay open?

```
import pygame
import time
import random

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

snake_width = 20
snake_height = 20

pygame.init()

game_width = 800
game_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((game_width,game_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game!')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class game:
    def _init_(self):
        snake_startx = (game_width/2)
        snake_starty = (game_heiht/2)

        x = thingx
        y = thingy
        x_change = 0

        gameExit = False
        while not gameExit:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                x_change = 5

            snake(white, thing_startx, thing_starty, snake_width, 
            snake_height, x_change)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


class snake:

    def _init_(self, color, thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, things):
        color = white
        thingx = snake_startx
        thingy = snake_starty
        thingw = snake_width
        thingh = snake_height
        things = x_change

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, [snake_startx,               
        snake_starty, 
        snake_width, snake_height,])


game()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Lots of issues with your code, but the first one is that your `_init_` function in your game is actually never called, so you never go to your while loop (try  putting some `print` statements in there to test that out. Rename it to `__init__` (double underscores, specially defined in python) and it should at least call all of that stuff (even if it is broken at the moment).

Comment: I suggest you uses Sentdex's beginner guide for Pygame. Which can be found on youtube.

Answer (score 2):

Had to rewrite more than half of the code. I wouldn't suggest following what guide you were using. Furthermore if you are very beginner at the python language I wouldn't recommend looking into object orientation just yet. First learn about data types, and loops. You can still make pygame projects without object orientation, but if you know how to use OOP then still use it.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

snake_width = 20
snake_height = 20

pygame.init()

game_width = 800
game_height = 600

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((game_width,game_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game!')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameDisplay.fill(black)

class snake:

    def __init__(self, color, thingw, thingh, movementspeedX, movementspeedY):
        self.color = color
        self.width = thingw
        self.height = thingh
        self.Xspeed = movementspeedX
        self.Yspeed = movementspeedY
        self.snake_startx = (game_width/2)
        self.snake_starty = (game_height/2)
        self.Xpos = self.snake_startx
        self.Ypos = self.snake_starty


    def Draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, self.color, pygame.Rect([self.Xpos, self.Ypos, self.width, self.height]))

    def Update(self):
        self.Xpos += self.Xspeed
        self.Ypos += self.Yspeed







SnakeObject = snake(white, snake_width, snake_height, x_change, y_change)
SnakeObject.Draw()

gameRunning = True
while gameRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("QUIT")
            pygame.quit()
            gameRunning = False
            quit() 

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                SnakeObject.Xspeed = -5
                SnakeObject.Yspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                SnakeObject.Xspeed = 5
                SnakeObject.Yspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                SnakeObject.Yspeed = 5
                SnakeObject.Xspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                SnakeObject.Yspeed = -5
                SnakeObject.Xspeed = 0

    print(SnakeObject.Yspeed)
    print(SnakeObject.Xspeed)
    SnakeObject.Update()
    SnakeObject.Draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: I can make it that there is only one block - doesn't keep extending.

Comment: My confusion with this is I had been using a guide that just defined things with def instead of class. That is currently how I made my mostly working code of what I was trying to create. Thanks for the help. I was trying to figure out how classes work since that seems to be how most people do things

Comment: Maybe don't look into object orientation just yet - involving classes. It took me about 4 years to partially understand OOP (object orientated programming) and how to partially use it. Note: When I say 4 years, it took me 4 years to get confident enough with Python to look into OOP